# Работа с тегом video

Tags: html5, javascript

Пытаюсь разобраться с управлением HTML5 тэга `<video>`. Прошу знающих людей ответить на вопросы.

1. Как можно программно перемотать видео к нужному времени?
2. Как узнать на каком участке времени сейчас проигрывается видео?
3. Как узнать длительность видео?

---

**UPDATE**

Хочу узнать длину видео, вот упрощённый код: http://jsfiddle.net/exp2W/2/
Видео загрузилось полностью, но событие **loadedmetadata** почему-то не произошло, прошу помощи..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rtfm [HTML5 Audio/Video DOM Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_av_dom.asp)

```
//Перемотка
document.getElementById("video1").currentTime = 3.5;
//Текущее время
alert(document.getElementById("video1").currentTime);
//Длительность видео, доступно только если видео загружено до конца, иначе NaN.
alert(document.getElementById("video1").duration);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку и ответ)